# C# application when build in Visual Studio 2010 64-bit does not work well

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

I'm working on a project on Device Simulator. If someone uses it and chooses a device to simulate, another application(Net Viewer) must be capable of detecting the device being simulated and the IP Address of the machine using it.

Here's my problem.
I am using a 64-bit OS and my other teammate is using 32-bit. When I tried to build the project on my PC and ran it, the Net Viewer wasn't able to detect my IP Address. But when my teammate built the project and ran it in his PC, it worked well. Then, we tried to run his built project in my PC and it worked fine.

What is causing this problem? We are both using anyCPU on Build Configuration.

Comment: can you provide some code, at least code section related to detecting Ip?

Comment: @daryal Our team is not the one who made the application capable of detecting the IP Address. Our application is the Device Simulator :)

Comment: what is the name of the application you are using? do the application have a seperate X64 version?

Comment: I'll have to ask the team that's working on it @daryal. You think it's the other program's flaws?

Comment: Did you try compile it explicitly for x64-cpus? Had a similar problem several time ago and could fix it this way.

Comment: I've had similar issues. I'm refraining from making this an answer because it isn't, but you should consider the following in your build: does your application require a 64-bit word length, e.g. for accuracy purposes when dealing with very large numbers? If the answer is no, then consider that your build should not be targeted at AnyCPU or x64.

Comment: I did @SvenKannenberg, and it still wont work.

Comment: @for-each I guess it is not related with your code, but related with other program. try checking the referenced external assemblies if any.

Comment: How are you calling the other "application"? Are you really using P/Invoke to call into it? If so, it is likely to be 32-bit and you will have to force your application to be 32-bit too (by changing the platform target to x86).

Comment: then what should it be @WimOmbelets?

Comment: we run it using its .exe @MatthewWatson

Comment: Configuration Active(Debug or Release), Platform Active(AnyCPU) and Platform Target: x86.

Comment: still no use @WimOmbelets.. :(

Comment: thanks to all those who left comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that an alert handler was causing us the pain. My teammate solved this issue. I will try to post the code snippet that caused the problem anytime soon.

Thanks to all those who shared their ideas. :)

Answer (score -1):

maybe force it to x86 instead of any cpu.
This way your application will run fine on 32bit and it wil run in WOW64 on your 64bit OS.

You can also force an application to run in 32bit modus with corflags.exe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

If this doesn't help you need to provide more details.

Comment: ANYCPU does exactly that.  Changing it from ANYCPU to x86 wouldn't solve the author's problem.